# Find lowest price each day in list of documents

Tags: elasticsearch

we store in elasticsearch  documents  with following fields

a (keyword)
b (keyword)
c (keyword)
date (date-time)
p (long)

how to find the lowest value p each `date` between 12/1/1920 and 12/31/1920 (pacific time zone)

Comment: you can try https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html , have not used but might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine 2 elements: query and pipeline aggregations. [Pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) are aggregations on aggregations - first you create buckets per day (first aggregation) and then you take the min of each.

Here's how the query should look like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "date": {
                "gte": "1920-12-01",
                "lte": "1920-12-31"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "daily": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "date",
                "calendar_interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "min_price": {
                    "min": {"field": "p"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```